# Loopback 4 REST Controller path returns NotFoundError 404

Tags: loopbackjs

Created a REST Controller with CRUD functions object via the CLI using 
`lb4 controller media`
pointing to an existing MediaRepository for an existing Entity Media model
both of which were generated using the lb4 CLI as well.

A MediaController class was created with all of the REST routes for /media*

The /ping route works fine so I looked for any special routing configuration for it to see if there might be a config messing for /media but nothing was obvious.

An HTTP Get request to /media response with a web page having the following content:

```
  <h1>NotFoundError</h1>
  <h2><em>404</em> Endpoint &#34;GET /media&#34; not found.</h2>
```

There is probably some fundamental configuration or setup that needs to happen but I am just not seeing it.

**MediaController class**

```
import {
  Count,
  CountSchema,
  Filter,
  repository,
  Where,
} from '@loopback/repository';
import {
  post,
  param,
  get,
  getFilterSchemaFor,
  getWhereSchemaFor,
  patch,
  put,
  del,
  requestBody, Request, RestBindings, ResponseObject
} from '@loopback/rest';
import { Media } from '../models';
import { MediaRepository } from '../repositories';

export class MediaController {
  constructor(
    @repository(MediaRepository)
    public mediaRepository: MediaRepository,
  ) { }

  @post('/media', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Media model instance',
        content: { 'application/json': { schema: { 'x-ts-type': Media } } },
      },
    },
  })
  async create(@requestBody() media: Media): Promise<Media> {
    return await this.mediaRepository.create(media);
  }

  @get('/media/count', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Media model count',
        content: { 'application/json': { schema: CountSchema } },
      },
    },
  })
  async count(
    @param.query.object('where', getWhereSchemaFor(Media)) where?: Where<Media>,
  ): Promise<Count> {
    return await this.mediaRepository.count();
  }

  @get('/media', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Media model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: { type: 'array', items: { 'x-ts-type': Media } },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async find(
    @param.query.object('filter', getFilterSchemaFor(Media)) filter?: Filter<Media>,
  ): Promise<Media[]> {
    return await this.mediaRepository.find(filter);
  }

  @patch('/media', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Media PATCH success count',
        content: { 'application/json': { schema: CountSchema } },
      },
    },
  })
  async updateAll(
    @requestBody() media: Media,
    @param.query.object('where', getWhereSchemaFor(Media)) where?: Where<Media>,
  ): Promise<Count> {
    return await this.mediaRepository.updateAll(media, where);
  }

  @get('/media/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Media model instance',
        content: { 'application/json': { schema: { 'x-ts-type': Media } } },
      },
    },
  })
  async findById(@param.path.string('id') id: string): Promise<Media> {
    return await this.mediaRepository.findById(id);
  }

  @patch('/media/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '204': {
        description: 'Media PATCH success',
      },
    },
  })
  async updateById(
    @param.path.string('id') id: string,
    @requestBody() media: Media,
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.mediaRepository.updateById(id, media);
  }

  @put('/media/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '204': {
        description: 'Media PUT success',
      },
    },
  })
  async replaceById(
    @param.path.string('id') id: string,
    @requestBody() media: Media,
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.mediaRepository.replaceById(id, media);
  }

  @del('/media/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '204': {
        description: 'Media DELETE success',
      },
    },
  })
  async deleteById(@param.path.string('id') id: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.mediaRepository.deleteById(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your MediaController.ts code ?

Answer (score 1):

So I set lb4 aside for a while while I evaluated other frameworks.

Came back to my lb4 demo project today. No changes to anything since then. Started the application.

```
npm run start
```

Browsed to **localhost:3000/media**

To my surprise it returned a json response. Now my response array was empty and it should have returned something as there were documents in the mongodb datasource but that is a separate issue to figure out.